# Change the name of a method in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a controller called pages with the following methods:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController


  def about
  end

  def privacy
  end

  def terms
  end

  def contact
  end
```

These are all static pages. I have created views with the same names. I would like to change the name of the 'contact' method to 'contact-us-form'. How can I achieve this? I have tried renaming the method to 'contact_us_form', but my view will not accept the same naming convention; it only works if I name it as 'contact-us-form'.

My routes.rb file:

```
 %w[about privacy terms contact].each do |page|
    get page, controller: "pages", action: page
  end
```

I'm using Rails 4. How do I only change the 'contact' url in routes.rb? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `contact` from the array you currently have, and place this in your routes.rb:

```
match "/contact_us_form", to: "pages#contact_us_form", via: "get", as: "contact_us_form"
```

You can alternatively use:

```
get "/contact_us_form", to: "pages#contact_us_form"
```

If you want the path to use dashes instead of underscores, replace "/contact_us_form" with "/contact-us-form".

For more information, check out the Routing section in the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html